# Code scanning warnings not making the check fail

Tags: github, github-actions

I have setup Snyk Github action to check for package vulnerabilities. The action runs the `snyk test` and `snyk code test` commands, generates two sarif files, and uploads them to Github.

One file is for `SnykCode` and other is for `Snyk Open Source`.

Both checks have *warning/errors*.

I have set up the protection rule in `Code security and analysis` tab as `any` and the branch rules. See the below images.

**Settings for Code security and analysis:**
[image: Code security and analysis]

---

**Branch protection rules:**
[image: Branch rules]

Even after these settings, `Snyk Open Source` is passing, and it says: *No new alerts changed code by this pull request*
[image]

[Here](https://github.com/sujeet-agrahari/node-express-modular-architecture/pull/10) is the repo to see for the action file and more details.

and below are the warning,
[image: warnings]